# How to use the SalesForce API?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I'm trying to use an express/node application to make an api call to the salesforce api and return me data according to the records I have with the account.

But it is returning this:

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]
```

Currently my code looks like this

```
  const express  = require('express')
  const app = express();
  var request = require('request');
  app.get('/',(req,res, next) =>{
    request({
      url: 'https://nav4.lightning.force.com/services/data"',
    }).pipe(res);
  });
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; app.listen(3000, ()=> 
console.log(`listening on port ${port}`))
```

I think my URL is wrong and might need authentication also.

Comment: which API you are using? apparently, almost all of the need authentication. in this case, you can authenticate the API by doing a session ID retrieved from the SOAP API login() call.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to authenticate first to https://login.salesforce.com.  I would suggest reading and following the documentation at [their documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm).  The username password flow is only recommended for testing purposes though, so once you get it working you might want to look into a different oauth flow if you are building a real application depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

For consume the Salesforce API below are the Details to notes.

1. Find which api to consume REST OR SOAP
2. Needs :

   1. Base URL
   2. Endpoint URL
   3. Consumer Key and secret key

This are the Point To archive

Below are for Your Reference

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services